# give a metric so that the function is continous

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

give a metric so that the  function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^2->\mathbb{R}, (x,y)\mapsto\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\in\mathbb{R}$ for $x\neq0$ or $y\neq0$,
(x,y)->for $x=0$ and $y=0$

is continuous in every point.

my problem: the funktion isnt continous in point (0,0) which metric is right, so that its continous in every point?

Comment: For instance, you could try to find a metric for which $(0,0)$ is an isolated point.

Comment: In polar coordinates, $f=\tfrac12\sin2\theta$.

Comment: i thought about d(x,y)=0 if x=y, and 1 if x ≠y . is this right?

Comment: Note that $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ is correct notation and $f:\mathbb R^2->\mathbb R$ is not, and "continuous" and "function" and "isn't" are correct spellings and "continous" and "funktion" and "isnt" are not. I corrected these in my edit to this question, and you put it back the way it was originally. Why? $\qquad$

Comment: sorry it was a mistake i wanted your edit :D im new here

Answer (score 1):

A universal solution would be: take the discrete metric on $\Bbb R^2$ and any metric whatsoever on $\Bbb R$. Can you check that $f$ will be continuous then?

Comment: no im not good in showing continuous... maybe i have to proove it thats right